# Why positive definite metric is necessary to define a topology

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

When we define a manifold we require that it locally looks like Euclidean. But even the Lorentzian metric in SR does not locally looks like Euclidean let alone the pseudo Riemannian metric used in GR. When, for example, the proper time vanishes as in a null path, the notion of an open ball, distance between events, and open basis cannot be used to define a topology.

Generally does a pseudo-Riemannian metric fit the definition of a manifold?

Comment: The "looks locally Euclidean" in the definition of manifold is a topological condition (or a smooth one, if you like, but whatever). It is not at all metrical.

Comment: Any useful reference suggestion to elaborate on the difference between topological structure and Euclidean structure (metrical) when defining a manifold?

Comment: Read the definition of manifold in any differential topology book, such as the book by Jack Lee or by Guilleman and Pollack. You will see that there is no reference to a Euclidean metric structure, nor to any other metric structure, in the definition of a manifold. You might well see, as a prod to the readers intuition, some words like "locally looks like Euclidean" or some variation. But those words do not refer to the local **metric** structure of Euclidean space, they refer only to the local **topological** structure of Euclidean space.